# How to find what exact java command jenkins runs in the background?

Tags: java, jenkins

So I am trying to reproduce an issue with my maven project (resource allocation issue, OOM - can't create native thread) which I see in Jenkins, locally. Hence, I wanted to run the exact java command that Jenkins would run (in the background) along with the arguments but am not sure where to find it, or how to figure that out. The only thing in the configuration I see is the maven commands I have given it.

Any pointers?

Comment: What is there to troubleshoot if you already know your problem? Just increase the memory.. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Answer (score 0):

Running `jps` will give you a list of instrumented JVMs running on a machine, including their runtime arguments.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html

Other useful commands:

Running `jmap` will give you a heapdump or a histogram of counts of all objects allocated on the heap.

Running `jvisualvm` will start a monitoring tool that allows you to study the JVM interactively.